# Removing list elements than are made of the same numbers

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a python a program that outputs a list like this:

```
['0007', '0016', '0025', '0034', '0043', '0052', '0061', '0070', '0106', '0115', '0124', '0133', '0142', '0151', '0160', '0205', '0214', '0223', '0232', '0241', '0250', '0304', '0313', '0322', '0331', '0340', '0403', '0412', '0421', '0430', '0502', '0511', '0520', '0601', '0610', '0700', '1006', '1015', '1024', '1033', '1042', '1051', '1060', '1105', '1114', '1123', '1132', '1141', '1150', '1204', '1213', '1222', '1231', '1240', '1303', '1312', '1321', '1330', '1402', '1411', '1420', '1501', '1510', '1600', '2005', '2014', '2023', '2032', '2041', '2050', '2104', '2113', '2122', '2131', '2140', '2203', '2212', '2221', '2230', '2302', '2311', '2320', '2401', '2410', '2500', '3004', '3013', '3022', '3031', '3040', '3103', '3112', '3121', '3130', '3202', '3211', '3220', '3301', '3310', '3400', '4003', '4012', '4021', '4030', '4102', '4111', '4120', '4201', '4210', '4300', '5002', '5011', '5020', '5101', '5110', '5200', '6001', '6010', '6100', '7000']
```

Theoretically it doesn't contain any duplicates, but it contains elements like '0007' and '7000' which are made of the same elements (3 zeros and 1 seven), standard filtering script won't catch them. How to make one than will remove them?
**After consultation it turns out than the order doesn't need to be kept, so your solution works well, thanks guys**

(If my post is a duplicate, then I am sorry but I couldn't find any the same questions. Please link one with a solution)

Comment: could possibly do with some regex magic?

Comment: Would your program consider `0016` and `0601` (for example) to be equal?

Comment: this is quite easy to do however which value are we returning, `0007` or `7000` and also @Aquarthur question is also relevant

Comment: You could define a set for each string and compare to the sets of other strings to check if they contain the same numbers.

Comment: @Aquarthur no, 0016 and 0601 are duplicates for me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind ending with a list of elements in a different order, here's an idea:

```
lst = [ ... your input ... ]
uniques = list({''.join(sorted(n)) for n in lst})
```

Explanation:

- Each string in the input is treated as a sorted list of characters, to treat same combinations in different order as the same case
- After that, we join each list back into a string
- We remove the duplicates by using a set comprehension
- Finally, we convert everything back into a list

The result looks like this:

```
['0016', '0124', '1222', '0115', '0034', '0025', '0223', '0007', '1123', '1114', '0133']
```

If you definitely want to keep only the first occurrence of an element, we can do it like this, but with a performance penalty:

```
result = []
for n in lst:
    unique = ''.join(sorted(n))
    if unique not in result:
        result.append(n)

result
=> ['0007', '0016', '0025', '0034', '0115', '0124', '0133', '0223', '1114', '1123', '1222']
```

Comment: this is wrong, order is not kept which OP has specified

Comment: @aws_apprentice I'm making a disclaimer about it at the beginning. keeping order will be hard for this problem

Comment: @ÓscarLópez actually, a `sorted()` on the list based on the original index would be a simple fix :)

Comment: @Idlehands do we have the guarantee that the input is sorted? I don't think so

Comment: @aws_apprentice I added an alternate answer that preserves order

Comment: I think OP just want to keep it the same order in which the `list` was passed in, so in essence, it doesn't have to be *sorted*, just maintain its order.  At least, that's how I interpreted it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `set()` to eliminate the duplicates, and then use `sorted()` to sort it with the original list order.

```
l = ['0007', '0016', '0025', '0034', '0043', '0052', '0061', '0070', '0106', '0115',  '0124', '0133', '0142', '0151', '0160', '0205', '0214', '0223', '0232', '0241', '0250', '0304', '0313', '0322', '0331', '0340', '0403', '0412', '0421', '0430', '0502', '0511', '0520', '0601', '0610', '0700', '1006', '1015', '1024', '1033', '1042', '1051', '1060', '1105', '1114', '1123', '1132', '1141', '1150', '1204', '1213', '1222', '1231', '1240', '1303', '1312', '1321', '1330', '1402', '1411', '1420', '1501', '1510', '1600', '2005', '2014', '2023', '2032', '2041', '2050', '2104', '2113', '2122', '2131', '2140', '2203', '2212', '2221', '2230', '2302', '2311', '2320', '2401', '2410', '2500', '3004', '3013', '3022', '3031', '3040', '3103', '3112', '3121', '3130', '3202', '3211', '3220', '3301', '3310', '3400', '4003', '4012', '4021', '4030', '4102', '4111', '4120', '4201', '4210', '4300', '5002', '5011', '5020', '5101', '5110', '5200', '6001', '6010', '6100', '7000']

sorted(list(set(''.join(sorted(x)) for x in l)), key=lambda x: l.index(x))

# ['0007', '0016', '0025', '0034', '0115', '0124', '0133', '0223', '1114', '1123', '1222']
```

Comment: man you stole my answer but I would wait until OP answer those two important questions that were posted

Comment: it has to retain the order, check OP's post this won't work

Comment: How about now, better?

Comment: for sure, this is the most straightforward and easiest answer to understand

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your elements to something which will *equal* for inputs like `"0007"` and `"7000"`.  The first thing which comes to mind is a counter.  Then put your elements in a `set()`, that will remove all your doubles:

```
from collections import Counter

input_elements = ['0007', '0016', '0025', '0034', '0043', '0052', '0061',
                  '0070', '0106', '0115', '0124', '0133', '0142', '0151',
                  '0160', '0205', '0214', '0223', '0232', '0241', '0250',
                  # ...
                  '7000']
s = set(Counter(e) for e in input_elements)
```

Now `s` will contain a set of all the input_elements with the doubles removed.

Unfortunately, `Counter`s are unhashable (what a pity).  So you could go with a tuple version of the Counters:

```
s = set(tuple(Counter(e).items()) for e in input_elements)
```

The most beautiful way I can think of is to create your own string class which has this specific property that things are considered equal when they have the same digits, regardless of their order:

```
class OrderIrrelevantString(str):
  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(''.join(sorted(self)))
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return sorted(self) == sorted(other)
```

Using this you can do it just like this:

```
s = set(OrderIrrelevantString(e) for e in input_elements)
```

The result then will be a set of `OrderIrrelevantString`s which will look and behave just like normal strings, so you probably can use them for whatever you want to do with them right away.

Comment: there is a clear syntax error here, `Counter` is not a hashable type

Comment: @aws_apprentice That's far from a Syntax error ;-)  But see my edit to address the issue.

Comment: your output looks way off from what I think OP wants

Comment: You might be right in that.  But it is a canonical form of the input he provided.  Things like a sorted version of the digits might well be something he didn't have in the input either.

Comment: I added another version which uses a special string subclass to achieve this in the best way I can think of.

Comment: this doesn't preserve order of the original input which OP has specified though

Comment: @aws_apprentice This question is a moving target.  When I first read it, nothing about (preserving) order was mentioned and I provided a solution for that.  It seems this has been added later, but by now it is specifically taken out again :-I ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` to sort the strings lexicographically to create unique entries that then you can store in a dictionary for fast lookup

```py
some_filter = {} # will create a lookup table for unique combinations of chars
filtered_results = [] # contain the final results

for x in result:
    hashable = "".join(sorted(x))
    if not some_filter.get(hashable):
        filtered_results.append(x)
        some_filter[hashable] = True

print(filtered_results)
```

Comment: you have an error here in the line `if not some_filter.get(sorted(x))`, it's not hashable

Answer (score 0):

Using `set` to check if already visited while maintaining the order. It will filter out the elements already seen before considering `'0007'` and `'7000'` same and in set we can keep counts of `0` and `7` rather than element itself

```
l = ['0007', '0016', '0025', '0034', '0043', '0052', '0061', '0070', '0106', '0115',  '0124', '0133', '0142', '0151', '0160', '0205', '0214', '0223', '0232', '0241', '0250', '0304', '0313', '0322', '0331', '0340', '0403', '0412', '0421', '0430', '0502', '0511', '0520', '0601', '0610', '0700', '1006', '1015', '1024', '1033', '1042', '1051', '1060', '1105', '1114', '1123', '1132', '1141', '1150', '1204', '1213', '1222', '1231', '1240', '1303', '1312', '1321', '1330', '1402', '1411', '1420', '1501', '1510', '1600', '2005', '2014', '2023', '2032', '2041', '2050', '2104', '2113', '2122', '2131', '2140', '2203', '2212', '2221', '2230', '2302', '2311', '2320', '2401', '2410', '2500', '3004', '3013', '3022', '3031', '3040', '3103', '3112', '3121', '3130', '3202', '3211', '3220', '3301', '3310', '3400', '4003', '4012', '4021', '4030', '4102', '4111', '4120', '4201', '4210', '4300', '5002', '5011', '5020', '5101', '5110', '5200', '6001', '6010', '6100', '7000']

from collections import Counter
s=set()
new_list=[]
for i in l:
    if tuple(Counter(sorted(i,key=int)).items()) in s:
        pass
    else:
        s.add(tuple(Counter(sorted(i,key=int)).items()))
        new_list.append(i)
```

Output:

```
['0007',
 '0016',
 '0025',
 '0034',
 '0115',
 '0124',
 '0133',
 '0223',
 '1114',
 '1123',
 '1222']
```

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate over your list and add each element to a set, before adding your element to the set you should check if the element/reverse element already exist. This will eliminate your issue

```
my_list = ['0007', '7000']
final = set()
for item in my_list:
    if item not in final and item[::-1] not in final:
        final.add(item)
final = list(final)
print(final) 
# output: ['0007']
```

Comment: sure, I hope is better